# How to passed Query Builder object to textarea?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

I have a view of Documents with list of data where I used joins here to combine them. I have a button here **Read** where it will takes me to text editor with a `content` column of selected row.

[image: SC]

**Controller:**

```
//SHOW
public function showDocuments()
{

    $documentLists = DB::table('document_user')->select('documents.title', 'documents.content', 'categories.category_type', 'users.username', 'document_user.dateReceived', 'documents.id')
        //Table name     //PK                  //FK
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'document_user.sender_id')
        ->join('documents', 'documents.id', '=', 'document_user.document_id')
        ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'documents.category_id')
        ->where('sender_id', '!=', Auth::id())
        ->where('user_id', '!=', Auth::id())->get();

    //VIEW
    return view ('document.show')->with('documentLists', $documentLists);
}
```

This is where all table records go.

```
//READ
public function readDocuments($id)
{
    $documentLists = DB::table('document_user')->select('documents.title', 'documents.content', 'categories.category_type', 'users.username', 'document_user.dateReceived', 'documents.id')
        //Table name     //PK                  //FK
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'document_user.sender_id')
        ->join('documents', 'documents.id', '=', 'document_user.document_id')
        ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'documents.category_id')
        ->where('sender_id', '!=', Auth::id())
        ->where('user_id', '!=', Auth::id())->get();


    return view ('document.read')->with('documentLists', $documentLists);
}
```

This is where it takes me to the `document.read` view and this view bring me text editor to show me the view of current content. As you can see I also include `'documents.id'` in the select query to get the id of current document.

**View:**

```
<table class = "table">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Content</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Sender</th>
                <th>Date Received</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        @foreach ($documentLists as $list)
            <tr class = "info">
            <td>{{ $list->title }}</td>
            <td>{{ strip_tags(substr($list->content, 0, 50)) }} {{  strlen($list->content) > 50 ? "..." : '' }}</td>
            <td>{{ $list->category_type }}</td>
            <td>{{ $list->username }}</td>
            <td>{{ date('M j, Y', strtotime($list->dateReceived)) }}</td>
            <td>
                <a href = "{{ route('document.read', $list->id) }}"><button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-info">Read</button></a>
            </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>

</table>
```

**read.blade.php**

```
<form class = "form-vertical">

<div class = "col-md-8">

    <div class = "form-group">

    <textarea id = "content" value = "{{ $documentList->content }}"></textarea>

    </div>

</div>

<form>
```

I didn't post anymore the script of tinymce. I just wanted to show in the textarea the `content` column that based on selected.

**routes:**

```
Route::get('/read/{id}',
[
'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\DocumentController@readDocuments',
'as' => 'document.read',
'middleware' => 'auth',
]);
```

But unfortunately it gives me a error.

> ErrorException in be7388ad5369ce939d52cb53ac5f3a4674217011.php line 34: Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\Users\JohnFrancis\LaravelFrancis\resources\views\document\read.blade.php)

But in my URL it prints me the correct id of the selected row. Any help or tips how can I solve this? Any help would appreciated!

**UPDATE**

After changing my `get()` to `find()` method on function `readDocuments($id)`. This works it prints me the value to textarea but only the first record. I tried to add `$id` in `find($id)` but returns me a error.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select `documents`.`title`, `documents`.`content`, `categories`.`category_type`, `users`.`username`, `document_user`.`dateReceived`, `documents`.`id` from `document_user` inner join `users` on `users`.`id` = `document_user`.`sender_id` inner join `documents` on `documents`.`id` = `document_user`.`document_id` inner join `categories` on `categories`.`id` = `documents`.`category_id` where `sender_id` != 13 and `user_id` != 13 and `id` = 137 limit 1)

**DATABASE DIAGRAM:**

[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

document_user migration

```
 public function up()
 {
    Schema::create('document_user',function (Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('document_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('document_id')->references('id')->on('documents')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->unsignedInteger('sender_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('sender_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');


        $table->dateTime('dateReceived')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
    });
 }
```

documents migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('documents', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('content');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

users migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('middle_name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('address');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->string('remember_token');

        $table->integer('role_permission_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('role_permission_id')->references('id')->on('roles_permissions_dt')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

categories migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('category_type');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**Model**

User:

```
public function documents()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Document', 'document_user', 'user_id', 'document_id');
}
```

Document:

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Category');
}

public function recipients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'document_user', 'document_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Category:

```
public function userDocuments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Document');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What's on line 34 in your read.blade.php file? is it the `<textarea id = "content" value = "{{ $documentList->content }}"></textarea>`? There's a variable there which probably returns null or is not an object.

Also, you could use `$documentList->content` between the textarea tags instead of the value HTML attribute like `<textarea>{{ $documentList->content }}</textarea>`

Update: You have to use `find($id)` at the end of your query so you can find the specific document by ID and display it in the show page.

Update 2: Use `$document = Document::with('category', 'users')->find($id);` in your `show($id)` method and pass the $document variable to the view.

Comment: Hi! It's only a `<div class = "form-group">` I already tried to put `{{ $documentLists->content }}` between `<textarea></textarea>` but still got the same error.

Comment: What about before or after that line?

Comment: I posted all the code in the `read.blade.php` see my answer. I used `find()` but only returns first record.

Comment: but you need only one record to display data on the show page. If you use get(), you have to loop over the records to display them using foreach in your view.

Comment: What exactly do you want to display on the read.blade.php view?

Comment: I only want to display the selected row in my tables. Please see my updated post.

Comment: use `find($id)` instead of `first($id)`

Comment: It's only typo error. I changed to `find($id)` but prints me an error.

Comment: That's happening because the query doesn't know which table the column `id` belongs to. Last part of the error in the where statement.

Comment: What should I change in my query? To avoid this error.

Comment: I am not sure, is this a many to many relationship? document_user being the pivot table?

Comment: Yes this is a many to many relationship. document_user is the pivot table.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this join? `Get the document by id with category and user information where the user id is different from the authenticated user id and the sender id is different from the authenticated user id`?

Comment: Yes you're correct. I just wanted to get the content of this query just to show this in my texteditor.

Comment: One more question: Which documents are you displaying on the documents list view? Are you displaying all documents where the user ID and sender ID are different from the authenticated user id?

Comment: If you already display them like I said, you don't need to do the where clause again, because, the user will only go to the show page and read documents which contain other user's documents. (documents where the user ID and sender ID are different from the authenticated user id)

Comment: I only displaying all the list of documents that the current user have.

Comment: Yes I already think that that I don't need the where clause because it's already show in the list. :)

Comment: It says 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::category()'. I will update my post so you can see my migrations.

Comment: what's the relationship name for the category table in your Document model class? change that name in the `with()` method instead of category.

Comment: One to many relationship. Categories -> documents. See my updated post :)

Comment: change categories to category and use category in the `with()` method.

Comment: It's already working. I changed to `$document = Document::find($id);` Thanks for your time bro.

Comment: No problem, but remember to use with() to eager load the relationships to avoid the n+1 problem when displaying records in that view.

Comment: What's the difference with that? I still not encounter using with() method.

Comment: Check out the [Eager Loading Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)